# Problems with ssh buffering of stderr without -tt

Tags: bash, ssh, stdout, stderr, flush

I'm trying to run a bash script remotely using ssh that outputs both to
stderr and stdout.
When I run normally in a terminal, I get the outputs in order.  But when
run with ssh I don't, for example:

```sh
$ ssh -T user@host bash <<< "echo hi >&2 && echo bye"
bye
hi
```

The stderr is delayed until after stdout.  This is in contrast to most
things I've seen online about buffering differences between stderr and
stdout that state that stderr is unbuffered (so would be output first).

But regardless, almost everything I try fails to get the lines to output
in order.  I've tried slapping stdbuf -e0 -o0 -i0 to just about every
part of the command (before the ssh, before the bash, before the echo).
I've tried different ways of passing the command (with `bash -c`,
without the `bash` at all).

There is one way I've found that DOES seem to work consistently is if I
pass -tt to ssh.  But using -tt seems to add its own can of worms, and
I'd prefer not to if possible.

Are there any other ways I can make ssh output buffering more "normal"?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I tries with a Mac client to a Debian server, and between two Debian servers.

Comment: @Barmar Hmmm!  I'm having the issue using a client (Fedora 32) with OpenSSH_8.3p1 connecting to server (RHEL 7.8 or Centos 7.6) with OpenSSH_7.4p1.  However on further investigation, it works fine between the two 7.4 servers.  Maybe a bug with the 8.3 ssh client?

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate for [unix.se]. Even though you're using SSH in a script, the issue is with the way the program works, which isn't an issue with your programming.

Comment: Fair enough.  Is there any way to transfer it over, or should I just create a new question there?

Comment: You can use the "flag" link to ask the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

The stderr is unbuffered only means the data is written to the fd immediately but it cannot guarantee when the written data will be handled by the receiver (pty, socket, pipe, ...).

For `ssh -T`, see this example (on a Debian Linux):

```
[STEP 103] # ssh -T 127.0.0.1 'ls -l /proc/$$/fd'
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug  4 13:59 0 -> pipe:[4610144]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug  4 13:59 1 -> pipe:[4610145]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug  4 13:59 2 -> pipe:[4610146]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug  4 13:59 3 -> /proc/23662/fd
[STEP 104] #
```

As it shows, `sshd` uses 3 pipes to communicate with its child process (this way `sshd` is able to distinguish between stdout data and stderr data). For the child it's guaranteed that data written to stderr will be sent to the pipe immediately but it's totally up to the `sshd` process to decide when the data will be handled. (**UPDATE**: And even after `sshd` sends the data back to the `ssh` client, it's still up to the `ssh` client to decide when it'll handle the received data.)

As for `ssh -tt`, a pty will be allocated for the child. The child process's stdin, stdout and stderr will all be opened on the pty and `sshd` cannot distinguish between stdour data and stderr data so the result is expected.

---

To verify `ssh -tt` cannot distinguish between stdout data and stderr data:

```
[STEP 109] # ssh -T 127.0.0.1 'echo hi; echo bye >&2'
hi
bye
[STEP 110] # ssh -T 127.0.0.1 'echo hi; echo bye >&2' 2> /dev/null
hi
[STEP 111] #
[STEP 112] # ssh -tt 127.0.0.1 'echo hi; echo bye >&2'
hi
bye
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
[STEP 113] # ssh -tt 127.0.0.1 'echo hi; echo bye >&2' 2> /dev/null
hi
bye
[STEP 114] #
```